# VBA fit all shapes in a column to the corresponding cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook like so:

```
     Column L

L5 = Image
L6 = Image
L7 = Image
L8 = Image
```

Column L has images copied and pasted into each cell. The images are all looking a bit mismatched if i'm honest.

I'd like to fit each image to the cell exactly. Is there a way of doing this for all images in the column without having to define the name of each image?

Here's what i've tried:

```
Sub FitImageToCell()
    With Sheet1.Shapes
        .Left = .TopLeftCell.Left
        .Top = .TopLeftCell.Top
        .Height = .TopLeftCell.Height
        .Width = .TopLeftCell.Width
    End With
End Sub
```

But i get a object doesn't support this property or method error.

Please can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there.
You're just missing telling it what shape in the shapes collection you're working with and telling it to go through each shape on the sheet.

This code will use a `For Each....Next` to cycle through the shapes collection and reference each shape using the `shp` variable.

```
Sub FitImageToCell()

    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
        With shp
            .Left = .TopLeftCell.Left
            .Top = .TopLeftCell.Top
            .Height = .TopLeftCell.Height
            .Width = .TopLeftCell.Width
        End With
    Next shp

End Sub
```

If you want to move just one shape then you can use:

```
Sub FitImageToCell1()

    With Sheet1.Shapes("Rectangle 1")
        .Left = .TopLeftCell.Left
        .Top = .TopLeftCell.Top
        .Height = .TopLeftCell.Height
        .Width = .TopLeftCell.Width
    End With

End Sub
```

Finally, if you want to move specific types of shape you can use:

```
Sub FitImageToCell()

    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
        With shp
            If .Type = msoAutoShape Then
                If .AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
                    .Left = .TopLeftCell.Left
                    .Top = .TopLeftCell.Top
                    .Height = .TopLeftCell.Height
                    .Width = .TopLeftCell.Width
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next shp

End Sub
```

There's a list of shape types here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432678(v=office.12).aspx

And a list of autoshape types here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432469(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks @Shai - didn't even notice that I was still using `shp` within the `With..End With` block.